# What code do I take to have just one of these buttons?

Tags: css, button, hover, css-selectors

I want to use just the button on the right:

http://cssdeck.com/item/preview/343/css-text-switcher

What code do I take to have just that button and not the first? I'm struggling because of all the descendant selectors..

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Want to learn more?</span>
        <span>Send us an email :)</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 320px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 -160px;
    list-style: none;
    font: .75em "lucida grande", arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}



li a {
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

li span {
    -webkit-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    transition: top .3s ease-out;
}

li span:first-child {
    background: #333;
    top: 0;
}

li span + span {
    background: #39f;
    top: 30px;
}

li a:hover span:first-child {
    top: -30px;
}

li a:hover span + span {
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: The biggest problem with your answer is that it's missing all the other vendor prefixes such as `-webkit`, which are present in the original CSS.

Comment: Close, but now you're missing for example `-ms-transition`. And the standard property `transition` should be last, not first. Just copy and paste the relevant rules from the original CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot: `-ms-transition` is obsolete, but good point on copying the relevant rules from the original CSS.

Comment: This does not seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/JXcB6/

Answer (score 1):

HTML (relevant code only):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Want to learn more?</span>
        <span>Send us an email :)</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>​
```

CSS (relevant code only):

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 320px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 -160px;
    list-style: none;
    font: .75em "lucida grande", arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}

li a {
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

li span {
    -webkit-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: top .3s ease-out;
    transition: top .3s ease-out;
}

li span:first-child {
    background: #333;
    top: 0;
}

li span + span {
    background: #39f;
    top: 30px;
}

li a:hover span:first-child {
    top: -30px;
}

li a:hover span + span {
    top: 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/TFntp/)
​

Comment: Basically all the `li:first-child` stuff should be deleted (since it refers specifically to the first button, and the `li + li` should be converted to just `li`, since we only have one button now, instead of two. Then we can delete the other button from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this: http://cssdeck.com/t/uHhhprW6